# Custom-filter CNN with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, filter, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to initialize a filter using keras, with my own function but I have an error, I dont know what  adding to my code for that parameter; 'partition_info'

Here is part of my code:

```
def kernel_init(self, shape, dtype=None):
    kernel = np.zeros(shape, dtype=dtype)
    kernel[:,:,0,0] = np.array([[-1,-2,-1], 
                                [0,0,0], 
                                [-1,-2,-1]])
    return kernel (dtype=dtype, shape=shape)
```

```
self.model = keras.Sequential([
             keras.layers.Conv2D(1, [3,3], kernel_initializer=self.kernel_init, 
             input_shape=(28,28,1), padding="valid"),
             keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
             keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
             keras.layers.Flatten(),
             keras.layers.Dense(batch_size, activation=tf.nn.relu),
             keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
             keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        ])
```

> TypeError: kernel_init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'

Comment: `def kernel_init(self,shape, dtype=None, partition_info=None):` should fix this I think.

Comment: Do you still have the error or is it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`def kernel_init(self,shape, dtype=None, partition_info=None):` should fix this.

The error is due to this check here in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a2f7f39d982682fa8de050e001522581570c510f/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer_utils.py#L124-L128).

Comment: Happy to know 

Comment: I'm new using keras, python etc, but the community is awasome! :D

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I added this part, it works perfect.

final code

```
def kernel_init(self, shape, dtype=tf.float64, partition_info=None):
            kernel = np.zeros(shape=shape)
            kernel[:,:,0,0] = np.array([[1,2,1],
                                        [0,0,0],
                                        [-1,-2,-1]])

            return kernel 


self.model = keras.Sequential([
             keras.layers.Conv2D(32, [3,3], kernel_initializer=self.kernel_init, 
             input_shape=(28,28,1), padding="valid"),
             keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
             keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
             keras.layers.Flatten(),
             keras.layers.Dense(batch_size, activation=tf.nn.relu),
             keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
             keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
             ])
```